# How to reset fileChooser component to blank

Tags: install4j

UI functionality is user selects a value in drop-down list, then picks a file using filechooser. When drop-down list value is changed, fileChooser must be rest.
FileChooser refers to a variable. Even after setting the variable to null and reinitialize(), it doesn't work. Sample code is below.

```
context.setVariable("fileChooserVariable", null); // var is set to null
```

`com.install4j.runtime.beans.formcomponents.FileChooserComponent fc = (com.install4j.runtime.beans.formcomponents.FileChooserComponent)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("9847");
   fc.initialize();
formEnvironment.reinitializeFormComponents();`

What is the way to reset fileChooser ?

Also if you could share link of install4j v5.1's javadoc, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the way to reset fileChooser ?

Based on your above code, you can call

```
fc.getConfigurationObject().setText("");
```

> Also if you could share link of install4j v5.1's javadoc, that would be great.

This is not available online, it's bundled with your install4j 5.1 distribution.